# What is a good Google Maps Generator?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am looking for a google maps API generator to save time? 
What do you recommend?

Update:
I want to generate (using my API key) a map of the US/WORLD and put markers are about 20 locations. Nothing crazy.

I am looking for something similar to this
http://schogini.us/ajax_google_map_api_code_generator/ajax_google_map_api_code_generator.php

Comment: What do you want it to generate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>What language do you need to be working in? There are both client-side and server-side tools for this.</strike> For client-side, I like jQuery's plugin [jMaps](http://github.com/digitalspaghetti/jmaps/tree/master).

Answer (score 3):

Try http://www.mapsofall.com/map-generator/, I think this is exactly you are looking for